# Guidelines to connect Sitecore 8.2.1 with SAP Hybris

Tags: commerce-connect

Upon reading I figured out two ways mentioned below to connect Hybris Commerce to Sitecore for digital e-commerce transactions:

1. Use the Sitecore Commerce Connect API with EPAM Connector.
2. Use the Sitecore Commerce Connect API with your own custom connector.

Is this accurate? Are there any other options?

Thanks in advance for your help.